# What is the observable to measure spin along some direction for a 2 qubit system?

Tags: measurement

Let $M$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrix corresponding to the observable to measure spin along some arbitrary axis $\vec{v}$. This matrix is given by following formula:

\begin{equation}
M = v_x  X + v_y  Y + v_z  Z
\end{equation}

where $X, Y, Z$ are $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrices and $\vec{v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$. E.g., see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/94118/2489)

Now if I have a 2 qubit system, then what is the $4 \times 4$ matrix to measure the spin of the first qubit along $\vec{v}$?

Comment: It should be $M\otimes I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @narip pointed out in a comment, it should be $M \otimes I$. Moreover, if you want to measure the second qubit along some axis $\vec{n}$ with corresponding matrix $N$, you can do $M \otimes N$.

Expanding this, we get

$$
\begin{align}
M \otimes N &= (v_x X_1 + v_y Y_1 + v_z Z_1) \otimes (n_x X_2 + n_y Y_2 + n_z Z_2) \\
&= v_xn_x X_1 X_2 + v_xn_yX_1Y_2 + v_xn_zX_1Z_2 \\
& \hspace{0.2in} + v_yn_xY_1X_2 + v_yn_yY_1Y_2 + v_yn_zY_1Z_2 \\
& \hspace{0.2in} + v_zn_xZ_1X_2 + v_zn_yZ_1Y_2 + v_zn_zZ_1Z_2
\end{align}
$$

where $X_1X_2 = X\otimes X$. (Wrote it like this to avoid writing a lot of $\otimes$s.) As @DaftWullie pointed out in his comment, this way you will get an observable with two eigenvalues and therefore your measurement will have two possible values.

**Update**

Following with the discussion on the comments, if you want are expecting to get four possible outcomes out of the measurement, you can do something like $M_1 + 2N_2$ given that $M$ and $N$ have eigenvalues $\pm 1$. Since both of these are of the form

$$
\begin{align}
\sigma_i &= \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\cos\phi - i\sin\theta\sin\phi \\ \sin\theta\cos\phi + i\sin\theta\sin\phi & -\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta(\cos\phi - i\sin\phi) \\ \sin\theta(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi) & -\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta \\ e^{i\phi}\sin\theta & -\cos\theta \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
$$

and therefore their characteristic equation is

$$
\begin{align}
\text{det}(\sigma_i - \lambda I) &= -(\cos\theta - \lambda)(\cos\theta + \lambda) - \sin^2\theta \\
&= -\cos^2\theta + \lambda^2 - \sin^2\theta \\
&= \lambda^2 - 1 = 0,
\end{align}
$$

which gives us $\lambda = \pm 1$, we are safe using $M_1 + 2N_2$.

Comment: $X\otimes X$ as an observable has two eigenvalues and hence the measurement has two outcomes. If you want to measure both qubits, you're probably expecting 4 outcomes (or, at least, you need a more precise statement of what you're expecting). In which case, you might be better with something like $X_1+2X_2$.

Comment: @DaftWullie you're right, thanks for your observation! Just some clarifications. Why is the coefficient of $2$ introduced? Would a observable like $M_1 + 2N_2$ with $M,N$ as defined above also work?

Comment: That depends on the eigenvalues of your operators. If $M$ and $N$ both have eignevalues $\pm 1$, it'll work fine. The trick is just to make sure that all the eigenvalues are distinct, i.e. $\pm1\pm 2$ doesn't have any repetitions, whereas if I'd just done $X_1+X_2$, the eigenvalues would have been $\pm1\pm 1$, and the 0 eigenvalue would have been repeated.

Comment: @DaftWullie I see, thank you! I didn’t know about this, could you point me to some theorem/concept/whatever where this is introduced?

Comment: I don't know if there is one. This is just the understanding I've come to over time.

Comment: Okay, thank you!